# Split javascript string into array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have this javscript string:

**response**

```
"[[[#],[b,#],[b,w,b,b,b,#],[b,#],[b,w,w,b,#]],[[b,#],[b,b,#],[b,b,w,#],[b,b,b,#],[b,b,#]],[[b,#],[b,b,b,b,#],[b,w,#],[b,b,b,#],[b,#]],[[b,#],[b,#],[w,w,w,#],[b,b,w,w,#],[b,w,#]],[[b,#],[b,b,b,b,#],[b,w,b,#],[b,w,#],[b,b,#]]]"
```

This corresponds to a board game and which field (e.g [b,w,b,b,b,#]) is a cell with **b**lack and **w**hite pieces. The **#** is the top of the stack.

I need to parse this in order to create an array of tiles.

I have this:

```
XMLscene.prototype.readBoard = function(data){
    var response = data.target.response;
    console.log("REPONSE  NO PARS" + response);
    response = response.split("],");
    console.log("REPONSE " + response);
    response[0] = response[0].substring(1);
    response[5] = response[5].substring(0, response[5].length - 2);
    for(var i = 0; i < response.length; i++)
    {
        response[i] = response[i].substring(1);
        response[i] = response[i].split("),");
        for(var j = 0; j < response[i].length; j++)
            response[i][j] = response[i][j].substring(5);
    }
    this.scene.board.loadTiles(response);
    //this.scene.client.getPrologRequest('quit', 0, 1);
};
```

to be parsed in this function:

```
gameBoard.prototype.loadTiles = function(board){
    console.log("BOARD : " + board);
    this.tiles = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < board.length; i++){
        for (var j = 0; j < board[i].length; j++){
            var player = board[i][j].split(",")[0];
            console.log("PLAYER : " + player);
            var type = board[i][j].split(",")[1];
            console.log("Type : " + type);
            if (type != "e") {
                var tile = this.createTile(type, this.scene ,i*6 + j+100, player);
                tile.line = i;
                tile.col = j;
                this.tiles.push(tile);
            }
        }
    }


}
```

The board structure I want is something like this:
for the first stack: `[#]`
It's an empty cell

`[b,#]` - A cell with one piece - black

`[b,w,w,b,#]` - A cell with a black piece in the bottom, then two white pieces and a black on the top, therefore the black player is the owner of the stack!

The stack owner is the player that have his piece on the top of the stack (closest to #)

Is there any way to get an array with each stack being the element of it?

Regards

Comment: Where are you getting the string from? Any chance you can make it actual JSON?

Comment: It is parsed from a PROLOG program. It represents my board on a sicstus prolog program

Comment: Then you could parse it further to JSON format and then parse it to javascript object, which should be much easier than parsing your string to object directly and on your own

Comment: How could I do that since I have a #?
I did something like `response = JSON.parse(response);`

Comment: The string is not valid JSON so you cannot use `JSON.parse`. Hence my question if you can make it JSON *before* you receive it in JavaScript.

Comment: @FelixKling that's what I thought. So, what are my chances?

Comment: Why do you split by `"),"` when that does not occur in your data?

Comment: could you add the board structure you are requiring

Comment: @diedu I added ths structure

Comment: What is `type`, and why is it the second character in the list, and how can it be `"e"` when it does not occur in the input?

Comment: the type is gonna be deleted, sorry, not important to this case.

Comment: Why do you want to keep the `#`? It seems unnecessary information as it is clear which way the stack is directed.

Comment: `JSON.parse(yourString.replace(/[bw#]/g, '"$&"'))`

Comment: Thomas comment should be an answer

Comment: @trincot I don't think it is necessary but on my PROLOG gameBoard it marks the top of the stack and it is needed for more predicates

Comment: `JSON.parse(str.replace(/[bw#]/g, '"$&"'), (k,v)=>Array.isArray(v) && v[0] === "#"? v.reverse(): v)` with fixed stack-order, so that the top (`#`) is always at the end

Comment: Why reverse? The end is at the right already...

Comment: @trincot, because as far as I understood, `#` can also be at the beginning of the Array, indicating that the top is at that end. And that extended code should normalize order for easier usage in JS. If I'm wrong, please ignore the comment.

Comment: Thank you everyone, it is solved. 
This community effort is overwhelming! Thanks a lot

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could transform the data to JSON like this, ignoring the hashes as they seem to give information that is already known (the stack ends at the right):

```
var response = JSON.parse(response.replace(/,?#/g, '').replace(/[bw]/g, '"$&"'));
```

Then you can for instance identify the current player for a stack at (i, j), like this:

```
var player = board[i][j].slice(-1)[0]; // last element on the stack
```

Snippet:

```js
// Sample data
var response = "[[[#],[b,#],[b,w,b,b,b,#],[b,#],[b,w,w,b,#]],[[b,#],[b,b,#],[b,b,w,#],[b,b,b,#],[b,b,#]],[[b,#],[b,b,b,b,#],[b,w,#],[b,b,b,#],[b,#]],[[b,#],[b,#],[w,w,w,#],[b,b,w,w,#],[b,w,#]],[[b,#],[b,b,b,b,#],[b,w,b,#],[b,w,#],[b,b,#]]]";

// Convert to nested array
var board = JSON.parse(response.replace(/,?#/g, '').replace(/[bw]/g, '"$&"'));

// Print the stack at 3, 3
console.log(board[3][3].join(','));

// Print player for that stack:
console.log(board[3][3].slice(-1)[0]);
```

Comment: That could be a chance but then I get this:
`,b,b,w,b,b,b,b,b,w,w,b,b,b,b,b,b,w,b,b,b,b,b,b,b,b,b,b,b,w,b,b,b,b,b,b,w,w,w,b,b,w,w,b,w,b,b,b,b,b,b,w,b,b,w,b,b`
And there's no way I could separate the stacks

Comment: It is not a single dimension array you get, but a 3D array. See the snippet I added, which illustrates that structure, shows one of the stacks, and the player for that stack.

Comment: You're superb! Thank you very much!

Comment: would you mind if I ask how do I put that result: `b,b,w,w` in an array? In order to iterate on it on my loadTiles?

Comment: It is already an array. In the snippet I did `join(',')` on it to turn it into the comma-separated string you see, but without it, it is an array. So you can do things like `board[i][j].forEach(function (value) { ..... do something with value--it is either 'w' or 'b' ... });`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/131753/discussion-between-perseverance-and-trincot).

Answer (score 0):

Modify your string to look like this...

```
var myString = '[[[#],[b,#],[b,w,b,b,b,#],[b,#],[b,w,w,b,#]],[[b,#],[b,b,#],[b,b,w,#],[b,b,b,#],[b,b,#]],[[b,#],[b,b,b,b,#],[b,w,#],[b,b,b,#],[b,#]],[[b,#],[b,#],[w,w,w,#],[b,b,w,w,#],[b,w,#]],[[b,#],[b,b,b,b,#],[b,w,b,#],[b,w,#],[b,b,#]]]'
```

replace elements with ""

Now run following:

```
var myArrayObject = JSON.parse(myString);
```

You just converted it to array.

Sample code:
https://fiddle.jshell.net/3gvzmwef/21/

---

Comment: I can't because it represents a PROLOG gameboard and it is made like that

Comment: @Perseverance you can always just do `'{' + response + '}'`

Comment: @spooky, what do you intend with this curly braces? That's still invalid JSON.

Comment: as @Ted said... Play with response object before it is passed to loadTiles.

Comment: I did that `response = '{' + response + '}';
    reponse = JSON.parse(response);
    console.log("REPONSE " + response); `

and: `Unexpected token [ in JSON at position 1`

Comment: @Thomas you were right... I needed to actually replace the inner values to with ""... Thanks for catching this. Apologies to write a solution without actually testing it. Updated sample code.

Answer (score 0):

A quick and dirty solution is to quote all your elements by using [String.prototype.replace()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) and then put the entire result in an [eval()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval):

```js
var str = "[[[#],[b,#],[b,w,b,b,b,#],[b,#],[b,w,w,b,#]],[[b,#],[b,b,#],[b,b,w,#],[b,b,b,#],[b,b,#]],[[b,#],[b,b,b,b,#],[b,w,#],[b,b,b,#],[b,#]],[[b,#],[b,#],[w,w,w,#],[b,b,w,w,#],[b,w,#]],[[b,#],[b,b,b,b,#],[b,w,b,#],[b,w,#],[b,b,#]]]";
var res = eval(str.replace(/[bw#]/g, "'$&'"));
console.log(res);
```